# how to reach and replace text inside of tags and nested tags ,elements on a site(not mine) in js

Tags: javascript, html, tags, html-lists

I am working on a javascript that act as a google translate do when you right click on a page and pick the translate to english option,

My problem is I am stuck on the algorithm phase that supposed to reach every text in the DOM of a site (not mine),
in some cases there are nested tags and inside there is a text that needs to be changed to another language 
Really need your help to know how can I do it

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('.ocms-container').querySelectorAll('*');
var elementsToArray= Array.from(elements);
let array = [...elementsToArray];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i].textContent);
}
```

This is what I've tried already but I want to know where is every text that I am replacing needs to be replaced at

Comment: `var elementsToArray= Array.from(elements);
let array = [...elementsToArray];` is not necessary. What do you mean by _"where is every text that I am replacing needs to be replaced at"_?

Comment: Are you trying to get the `.nodeName`?

Comment: guest271314 I meant that I don't know if I need to replace each word of the translated language inside the belonged tag or i just need to send the word to the api and it will translate it at the same time and iteration it was found?

Comment: I'm trying to get the text out of the childNodes but some are inside nested divs and other tags and some are just inside a single tag like span or a or li or div

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop for each childNode starting from a root element, so the way you can do it by checking if current node has `childNodes`, now to get the text inside a node, you can check their `nodeType`, please check this out [NodeType Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), this will help you to understand which kind of nodes the DOM have, so a working code to collect all text nodes could be:

```
const root = document.querySelector('body');
const queue = [root];
const textNodes = [];
const NODE_TEXT = 3;

while(queue.length) {
    const node = queue.shift();
    const children = node.childNodes;
    if (children && children.length > 0) {
        const childrenAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(children);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(queue, childrenAsArray);
    }
    if (node.nodeType === NODE_TEXT) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
}

// finally you can console.log all the text nodes collected
console.log(textNodes);
```

If you run this code into any site in the Chrome console dev tools, you can have all text text node into the site.

Hope you can find it useful.

### EDIT

in order to get the text value for each node you should first verify some rules before getting the text, so let' get started.

1. exclude the `script`, 'style', 'noscript' and `code` tags
2. check if the current node has one child node
3. check if the child node is a text node (NODE_TEXT = 3)
4. check if the child node is not empty

So let's start, by adding these rules

```
const root = document.querySelector('body');
const queue = [root];
const textNodes = [];
const NODE_TEXT = 3;
const exclude = ["SCRIPT", "STYLE", "CODE", "NOSCRIPT"]; // add exclude tags

// check if node is not the exclude one
function isNodeAllow(node){
return exclude.indexOf(node.tagName) === -1;
}

// define a helper function to check if has one child node
function hasOneChildNode(node){
return node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length === 1;
}

// check if node is not the exclude one
function isChildNodeText(node){
return node.childNodes[0].nodeType === NODE_TEXT;
}

// check if node is not the exclude one
function isNotEmpty(node){
return Boolean(node.innerText.trim());
}

while(queue.length) {
    const node = queue.shift();
    const children = node.children;
    if (children && children.length > 0) {
        const childrenAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(children);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(queue, childrenAsArray);
    }
    if (isNodeAllow(node) && hasOneChildNode(node) && isChildNodeText(node) && isNotEmpty(node)) {
        // here you can translate the text.
        // node.innerText will return the text to be translated
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
}

// finally you can have all the collected text into the site
console.log(textNodes)
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Remember you can loop using a queue or as a recursive way too

Comment: I don't know what nodes are `querySelectorAll('*')`, but to get the text from a node you should get only one node in order to get the text inside it, so remember `querySelectorAll('*')` will return an array of nodes if it matches with some nodes

Comment: @ShaharAlaluf if you want to get the text inside the html tags, you will get it with the code above, no matter in the text is in chinese or not, you will get them, for example in the code above, in the condition `if(node.nodeType === NODE_TEXT)` you can get the text by writing `node.innerText` and once you got the text you can start to translation process to then replace it.

Comment: @ShaharAlaluf I just edited my answer, I explained the rules you should follow to get the text for each tag to be translated

Comment: well It been a long journey but i managed to activate this code to my needs thank you so much dear friend

Comment: @ShaharAlaluf I hope you can found it useful, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive example below will find nodes containing text and with no children.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        text1
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>text2</p>
        <span>text3 span</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            text4
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    li1
                </li>
                <li>
                    li2
                </li>
                <li>
                    li3
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    class DOMNodeToTranslate {
        constructor(elName, elText) {
            this.elName = elName;
            this.elText = elText;
        }

        translate() {
            // translation algorithm
        }

        // ...other methods
    }

    function findTextNodes(root) {
        if (root.childNodes.length > 1) {

            root.childNodes.forEach(node => {

                findTextNodes(node);

                let nodeText = node.textContent.replace(/(^(\s|\n|\t)+)|((\s|\n|\t)+$)/gm, '');
                if (nodeText != '' && node.childNodes.length == 1 && node.nodeName != 'SCRIPT') {
                    let elObject = new DOMNodeToTranslate(node.nodeName, nodeText);
                    toTanslate.push(elObject);
                }

            });

        }
    }

    let toTanslate = [];
    let rootElement = document.querySelector('body');
    findTextNodes(rootElement);

    console.log(toTanslate);
</script>
```

Comment: You won't really need the class - I just put it there for fun.

Comment: thank you for your help my friend I appreciate it a lot